# Paste content from the clipboard automatically when I open the TinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce, paste, pageload, clipboarddata

I am trying to paste the content from the clipboard automatically when I open the tinyMce Editor.

I have already used-

```
var a=window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
tinymce.get("id1").setContent(a);
```

but unable to get the content on the editor, but able to get it in the alert on IE(only)

however when i use 
    tinymce.get("id1").setContent('a');

I can get the content 'a' on the editor.

Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly let us know what has been tried yet and what is the problem that you are facing.

Comment: @MohitKanwar and I have used the above codes on window.onload